# How can I make it so when I ssh myself my system info shows up when I log in?

Tags: ssh, system

I have a vds and when I log in my system info shows up and I'm wondering how I can do this with my desktop that's running 12.04 LTS because I love the feature.

Here is a picture that shows the difference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out the *message of the day* files. You can find the message

> Welcome to Ubuntu 13.04 (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-26-generic x86_64)
>
> - Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

in `/etc/motd`.

There are some other files which might be worthy to look into, just run `locate motd` (from the terminal) and all relevant files will be listed.